# Custom checkmark not showing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a custom radio checkbox but the checkmark is not showing for some reason, you cannot click and unclick to have the checkmark appear.

Is it possible to make it appear and clickable this checkmark?

```css
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.here .checkmark {
    display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.here .checkmark:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.here inp_cont:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: black;
}

.here .checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.here inp_cont:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

.here .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="here"><span class="checkmark"></span> 
        <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="hello" id="hello" class='inp_cont' required value="here" /> Click in the box</div>
```

Comment: ... I think you are missing opacity after you click the box? You set the opacity to 0 by default; but, I don't see when the opacity is increased.

Comment: @Tyler - opacity 0 is meant to hide the original default checkbox... i aim to replace it.

Comment: But, if you never increase opacity afterwards, won't it always be invisible (0 opacity = not visible)? So the checkbox would never appear on the browser.

Comment: I don't see where you let the user click anything. The only clickable thing is the input, but it's invisible. So where is the user supposed to click?

Comment: What's `inp_cont`? Did you forget the `.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of things wrong with your code (although not with your approach).

1. There is nothing for the user to click on. Solution: turn the span with class="checkmark" into a label for the input.
2. As @j08691 notices in the comments, `inp_cont` doesn't exist. Solution: change this to a selector for the checkbox; in this particular case, just `input` will do (since there is only one).
3. You have `input:check ~ .checkmark` in the CSS, but this will ony work if the .checkmark comes *after* the input in the source. Solution: swap them around.

And then it works.

```css
input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.here .checkmark {
    display: inline-block;
 margin-right: 20px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.here .checkmark:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.here input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: black;
}

.here .checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}

.here input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}

.here .checkmark:after {
    left: 9px;
    top: 5px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid white;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="here">
 <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="hello" id="hello" class='inp_cont' required value="here" />
 <label for="hello" class="checkmark"></label>
 Click in the box</div>
```